# sum of subselects to new column

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I have an issue with summing up together two generated values from subselects. The typical sum of two columns (col1 + col2) is not working in this case, what is wrong with it?

```
 SELECT 
 (
 SELECT COUNT(*)  
 FROM contract c2
 WHERE
 1=1
 AND c2.d_from      <= TO_DATE('31.10.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
 AND c2.d_to         > TO_DATE('31.10.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
 AND c2.d_created   <= TO_DATE('31.10.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
 AND c2.cd_system = 'I'     
 AND c2.cd_product = 'D'
 AND c2.cd_subproduct IN ( '10' ) 
 AND c2.cd_subproduct NOT IN ( '80')
 AND c2.cd_status NOT IN ('09','05')
 ) AS without ,
 (
 SELECT COUNT(*)  
 FROM contract c2
 WHERE
 1=1
 AND c2.d_from      <= TO_DATE('31.10.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
 AND c2.d_to         > TO_DATE('31.10.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
 AND c2.d_created   <= TO_DATE('31.10.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
 AND c2.cd_system = 'I'     
 AND c2.cd_product = 'D'
 AND c2.cd_subproduct IN (( '10' ), ( '80' ))
 AND c2.cd_status NOT IN ('09','05')
 ) AS withs,

 (
 SELECT withs,  without, 
  (
  SELECT COUNT(*)  
  FROM contract c2
  WHERE
  1=1
  AND c2.d_from      <= TO_DATE('31.10.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
  AND c2.d_to         > TO_DATE('31.10.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
  AND c2.d_created   <= TO_DATE('31.10.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
  AND c2.cd_system = 'I'     
  AND c2.cd_product = 'D'
  AND c2.cd_subproduct IN ( '10' ) 
  AND c2.cd_subproduct NOT IN ( '80')
  AND c2.cd_status NOT IN ('09','05')
  ) + 
  (
  SELECT COUNT(*)  
  FROM contract c2
  WHERE
  1=1
  AND c2.d_from      <= TO_DATE('31.10.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
  AND c2.d_to         > TO_DATE('31.10.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
  AND c2.d_created   <= TO_DATE('31.10.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
  AND c2.cd_system = 'I'     
  AND c2.cd_product = 'D'
  AND c2.cd_subproduct IN (( '10' ), ( '80' ))
  AND c2.cd_status NOT IN ('09','05')
  ) as both
 FROM contract c2  
 )
FROM dual
;
```

Each subselect generates one row only. And I need to sum up the first two subselects to get the final number like in this  table. However the error message alerts to too many rows. Thank you for your help in advance!

```
without  withs  both
25        15     50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for testing purpose I have used dual .

```
SELECT  
(SELECT 1 FROM  dual 
 ) AS without ,
 (
 SELECT 2 FROM dual 
 ) AS withs,

 (

 (
  SELECT 3 FROM dual 
  ) + 
  (
  SELECT 4 FROM  dual 
  ) 

 ) AS both
 FROM dual
```

and it works. Check this for your table and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like

```
select
 sum(case when
     c2.cd_subproduct IN (( '10' ), ( '80' ))
     AND c2.cd_status NOT IN ('09','05') 
     then 1 else 0
     end)
as without,
sum(case when
    c2.cd_subproduct IN (( '10' ), ( '80' ))
    AND c2.cd_status NOT IN ('09','05')
    then 1 else 0
    end)
as withs,
sum(case when
    AND c2.cd_subproduct IN (( '10' ), ( '80' ))
    AND c2.cd_status NOT IN ('09','05')
    then 1 else 0
    end)
as both
from contract c2
where...
```

**Update** put query in With statement then sum withs and without

```
with totals as(
 select
  sum(case when
      c2.cd_subproduct IN (( '10' ), ( '80' ))
      AND c2.cd_status NOT IN ('09','05') 
      then 1 else 0
     end) as without,
 sum(case when
     c2.cd_subproduct IN (( '10' ), ( '80' ))
     AND c2.cd_status NOT IN ('09','05')
     then 1 else 0
     end) as withs
 from contract c2
 where...
)

select without, withs, sum(without + withs) as both
from totals
group by without, withs
```

Comment: Hey it is a very good select, however the both section gives me the same results as without after the correction. Withs and without fit though.

Comment: try removing the both section and summing the withs and withouts in a With statement...I'll update my answer